# How can I add a 'name' field in a custom control?

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, lotus-notes

In forms, there is a 'name' field which upon clicking opens address book names through which I can select the list of users. I want to do the same thing through custom control but not getting how to achieve it as there is no option of 'name' field in Custom controls.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Name Picker** `<xe:namePicker ...>` from Extension Library with data provider "dominoNABNamePicker". It is part of Notes 9.

This is a simple example how to use it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputText1"
            value="#{sessionScope.name}">
        </xp:inputText>
        <xe:namePicker
            id="namePicker1"
            for="inputText1">
            <xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker></xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProvider>
        </xe:namePicker>
</xp:view>
```

You can find more examples including multiselection or typeahead in XPages Extension Library Demo database in Domino_Pickers.xsp. You can find the demo database in [download package on OpenNTF](https://extlib.openntf.org/).

Comment: With more recent versions of Extension Library on OpenNTF there are some enhancements to the Name Picker, most notably being able to define the returnNameFormat (to get canonical, required by Readers fields) and restricting search results. See the pull request for details https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/pull/14